# How do i grab the main headline at cnn?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

[image]

Trying to only grab the "Ambassador calls trump inept" but i cant seem to land in that area. I have tried  pulling "h2" and the class as well as "strong tags but cant seem to find anything. The code below i left it as is, its the only thing i can get to display.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(data.text,'html.parser')
    for rows in soup.find_all('li'):
        for x in soup.findChildren('div'):
            print(x)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The page loads the data dynamically. If you inspect, to what URLs the page is making requests (eg. in Firefox Developer Tools) you will find that the data is in different url. Unfortunately, this url (`https://edition.cnn.com/data/ocs/section/index.html:intl_homepage1-zone-1/views/zones/common/zone-manager.izl`) is constructed dynamically:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://edition.cnn.com/data/ocs/section/index.html:intl_homepage1-zone-1/views/zones/common/zone-manager.izl'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, 'lxml')
print(soup.h2.text)
```

Prints:

```
UK ambassador calls Trump 'inept' and 'insecure'
```

Comment: Thank you for the information. Shouldnt i also be able to inspect in chrome and see this same information? Or is this something firefox addresses and not chrome?

Again, thanks for the information!

Comment: @user420154 You can do it also in Chrome. I just find Firefox tools easier to use for me.

Comment: Thank you, ill try to find that area you seen the real URL in.